# Getting an error with mailchimp plugin

Tags: smartgroups, mailchimp

We have installed the mailchimp plugin from veda consulting.  The plugin was working until recently

when I try to access this
page https://www.fremantlechamber.com.au/civicrm/mailchimp/settings?reset=1

I get the error below.  I checked the groups and they are all correctly
synced to the plugin and not referencing a list in Mailchimp that does
not exist.

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
Invalid MailChimp List ID: e33355b9f6

Return to home page. https://www.fremantlechamber.com.au/

Can you please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CiviCRM group is mapped to the list ID of a Mailchimp list or interest which is not available (deleted on Mailchimp, or belonging to another Mailchimp API key, or ...). Review the groups which are syncing to Mailchimp, and make sure each one of those connects to a current / valid List or Group in Mailchimp.

There are DB tables you might be able to identify the specific group ID from. Look in `civicrm_value_mailchimp_settings`

```
mysql> select * from civicrm_value_mailchimp_settings;
+------+-----------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| id   | entity_id | mc_list_id | mc_grouping_id | mc_group_id | is_mc_update_grouping |
+------+-----------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------------+
|    1 |       123 | aabbccddee |                |             |                  NULL |
|    2 |       124 | 1122334455 | beadbeadbe     | aceaceacea  |                     1 |
|    3 |       125 | 9988776655 | facefacefa     | deadeddead  |                     1 |
+------+-----------+------------+----------------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

The column `entity_id` is the relevant CiviCRM Group ID, and you'll see `e33355b9f6` in one of your other columns I expect.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I checked that each civi group was connected to a corresponding mailchimp list. Any other ideas.?  What do you mean by a valid list?

Comment: Mailchimp has Lists (list you email) and then Groups (interest groups within lists).

Comment: It might not be what you're hitting, but I identified & submitted a fix for what seems to be a bug in syncing from Mailchimp to CiviCRM, due to changes in Mailchimp's data format for their API v3. See [GH-238: Interests incorrectly updated on Profile update Webhook](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mailchimp/issues/238) on the extension's Github.

Comment: The error message is saying that the list that you have in CiviCRM identified by `e333...` no longer exists (or is accessible, as Chris says) at Mailchimp. Unfortunately Mailchimp don't make this stuff easy, but if you go to the "List name and defaults" page *on mailchimp.com* for the list it will say there what the List ID is. My bet is that you won't find a list with the list ID `e33355b9f6`.